# im trying this question but i just cant seem to get the code working, after the sentence ive attached a picture of my work

Tags: python

1. load_datafile() takes a single string  parameter representing the  filename of a  datafile.
   This function must read the content of the file, convert all letters to their lowercase, and store
   the result in a string, and finally return that string. I will refer to this string as data throughout
   this specification, you may rename it. You must also handle all exceptions in case the datafile
   is not available.

Sample output:

> > > data = load_datafile('harry.txt')
> > > print(data)
> > > the hottest day of the summer so far was drawing to a close and a drowsy silence
> > > lay over the large, square houses of privet drive.

2. load_wordfile() takes a single string argument representing  the filename of a wordfile.
   This function must read the content of the wordfile and store all words in a one-dimensional
   list  and  return  the  list.  Make  sure  that  the  words  do  not  have  any  additional  whitespace  or newline  character  in  them.  You  must  also  handle  all  exceptions  in  case  the  files  are  not
   available.

Sample outputs:

> > > pos_words = load_wordfile("positivewords.txt")
> > > print(pos_words[2:9])
> > > ['abundance',  'abundant',  'accessable',  'accessible',  'acclaim',  'acclaimed',
> > > 'acclamation']

> > > neg_words = load_wordfile("negativewords.txt")
> > > print(neg_words[10:19])
> > > ['aborts',  'abrade',  'abrasive',  'abrupt',  'abruptly',  'abscond',  'absence',
> > > 'absent-minded', 'absentee']

---

### MY CODE BELOW

```
def load_datafile('harryPotter.txt'):

    data = ""

    with open('harryPotter.txt') as file:

        lines = file.readlines()

        temp = lines[-1].lower()

    return data
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask].

Comment: Did you want to return data or temp? Did you want a line or a list of strings? Also, you have invalid syntax for passing a parameter and just read a hardcoded filename instead.

Comment: it should return a line of data and how do i fix the other issue

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has two main problems. The first one is that you are assigning an empty string to the variable `data` and returning it, so no matter what you do with the contents of the file you always return an empty string. The second one is that `file.readlines()` returns a list of strings, where each line in the file is an element on the list and you are only converting the last element `lines[-1]` to lowercase.

To fix your code you should make sure that you store the contents of the file on the `data` variable and you should apply the `lower()` function to each line on the file and not just the last one. Something like this:

```
def load_datafile(file_name):
    data = ''

    with open(file_name) as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            data = data + line.lower() + '\n'
    return data
```

The previous example is not the best way of doing this but it's very easy to understand what is happening and I think that is more important when you are starting. To make it more efficient you might want to change it to:

```
def load_datafile(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as file:
        return '\n'.join(line.lower() for line in file.readlines())
```